# AVL Tree Data Being Overwritten

Tags: c++, pdf, data-structures, tree, avl-tree

I am writing a project that indexes the words of multiple PDF files and stores the word along with the file location into an index that is an AVL Tree. I have a problem where after a certain point of parsing a PDF and adding the words to the AVL tree index, the index deletes/overwrites/does something where when the indexing is complete, only the data from one pdf is left in the tree.

Here is the insert method of the AVL Tree class.

```
template<class T>
void avlTree<T>::insert(T data, avlNode<T>*& node){
    //if we are at a nullptr, then insert the new node
    if(node==nullptr){
        node = new avlNode<T>(data);
    }
    //if the data to insert is less than the node we are lookingg at
    //then next compare it to the left node
    else if(data < node->key){
        insert(data, node->left);
        //if left subtree is larger than right, then a
        //case 1 or 2 is present
        if(height(node->left)-height(node->right)==2){
            //if data was inserted to the left
            //LL or Case 1
            if(data<node->left->key){
                leftRotate(node);
            }
            //LR or case 2
            else{
                doubleLeftRotate(node);
            }
        }
    }
    //if greater then compare it to the right node
    else if(data>node->key){
        insert(data, node->right);
        //if right subtree is larger than the left, then
        //a case 3 or 4 is present
        if(height(node->right)-height(node->left)==2){
            //if data was inserted to the left
            //LL or Case 1
            if(data>node->right->key){
                //RR or case 4
                rightRotate(node);
            }
            //RL or case 3
            else{
                doubleRightRotate(node);
            }
        }
    }
    //if nodes are equal case
    else{
        //do nothing
    }

    //update the height of the node
    node->height = 1 + max(height(node->left),height(node->right));
}
```

This is the function call in the AVL Index class that contains an AVL Tree (index) as a data member

```
void avlIndex::addWord(indexEntry iE){
    index.insert(iE);
}
```

The AVL Tree Nodes contain IndexEntry objects. Here is the constructor for that. entry is the word being indexed, entryLocation is a vector of fileNames where the words appears, and locCount is a vector with the number of appearances at each file.

```
//argument constructor
indexEntry::indexEntry(string what, string where){
    entry = what;
    entryLocation.push_back(where);
    locCount.push_back(1);
}
```

Finally, here is where an index entry is called to be added to the index where add is the word and is a string

```
    indexEntry entry(add,fileName);
    //check if word is already indexed
    if(!(index->isIn(entry))){
        //if it is not in, add a new entry
        index->addWord(entry);
    }
```

The program works as expected through about 1.5-2.5 PDFs depending on their size, and then the entire tree only contains the information from one pdf. Just wondering what could be causing this?

Comment: Perhaps one of the edge cases in your rotation code is broken.

Comment: How many nodes does the tree contain, when the error occurs?

Comment: I think @paddy may be correct. I started testing the Avl Tree with random Ints instead of objects, and it occurs after about 10 or so nodes usually. I'll probably have to write out the tree on paper to see which rotation(s) is wrong.

Comment: Just confirmed that something is up with the rotations. Occurs when the root node has to be changed, and all of the pointers don't get correctly reassigned. Thanks for the help.